# Count of col1 over order by col2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table t (col1 int,col2 varchar(10)) 
insert into t values(10,'val')
insert into t values(20,null)
insert into t values(10,'val3')
insert into t values(40,'val1')
insert into t values(50,null)
insert into t values(60,'val')

--1.
SELECT *,COUNT(COL2) OVER (ORDER BY COL1) FROM T

--2.
SELECT *,COUNT(COL1) OVER (ORDER BY COL2) FROM T
```

I am not able to understand the output of two select query mentioned above.. can anybody elaborate.

Comment: Have a look at [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql). it always helps to do a little research yourself; it helps you learn more. If you have more questions, update your post with what specific parts you don't understand.

Comment: In addition to @Larnu, Read this for little elaborated example: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Over+Clause/132079/

Answer (score 2):

1. The count column will contain the accumilative number of values in col2 that are not null, sorted by the value of col 1

```
SELECT *,COUNT(COL2) OVER (ORDER BY COL1) AS [count]
FROM T
ORDER BY COL1
```

Results:

```
col1    col2    count   --explanation
10      val3    2       --The first two values of col1 are the same, and the values of col2 are not null.
10      val     2       --The first two values of col1 are the same, and the values of col2 are not null.
20      NULL    2       --A new value of col1, but col2 is null so it's not counted.
40      val1    3       --A new value of col1, and col2 is not null.
50      NULL    3       --A new value of col1, but col2 is null so it's not counted.
60      val     4       --A new value of col1, and col2 is not null.
```

2. Basically the same, just reverse the columns:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(COL1) OVER (ORDER BY COL2) As col1Count
FROM T
ORDER BY  COL2
```

Results:

```
col1    col2    col1Count    --explanation
20      NULL    2            --The first two values of col2 are the same (both null), and the values of col1 are not null.
50      NULL    2            --The first two values of col2 are the same (both null), and the values of col1 are not null.
60      val     4            --The next two values of col2 are the same (both 'val'), and the values of col1 are not null.
10      val     4            --The next two values of col2 are the same (both 'val'), and the values of col1 are not null.
40      val1    5            --A new value of col2, and col1 is not null.
10      val3    6            --A new value of col2, and col1 is not null.
```